# Slow server response, lots of free CPU and RAM

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloudflare

I've been pulling my hair out for the last few days on this and have finally succumbed to asking for help.

Quick run down... I've got a website that receives around 10-20K visits a day. I'm using a [large EC2 Instance from Amazon](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/#instance-details) and a [small RDS instance](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/#features).

I have Wordpress Multisite installed on there with a variety of plugins etc. I'm using APC and Memcache, as well as Varnish. All static content (images, JS, CSS etc) is stored on a CDN. I also have CLoudFlare sitting in front of all this.

My problem is that despite having over 5 gig of spare RAM and the CPU never spiking above 40%, the response time of the website is really poor. Likewise, my RDS instance never peaks over 20% CPU usage.

Unless I'm un-registered user hitting a Varnish cached page, then it loads lightning quick.

So I'm not exactly sure what I can be doing to try and troubleshoot the problem. I've run various profilers and plugin checkers to see if any of them are causing issues in the Wordpress install and none have shown red flags.

Could it be my Apache settings? PHP settings? Something else? I'm basically asking for this I can check/change/monitor to try and debug this problem. It's really frustrating.

Thanks in advance and if you need/want any more info, just let me know.

Comment: Have you performed any test like http://www.webpagetest.org/ ? if so, can you post it here?

Comment: Here you go.

http://www.webpagetest.org/result/131012_VV_269/

CloudFlare threw up an error due to it taking so long.

Comment: Can you do an ip trace to see if the site is actually being hit?

Comment: Here's a traceroute: http://www.webpagetest.org/result/131012_2Y_2G9/

Comment: Is your RDS server in the same AZ as your web server?

Comment: Yes, both EC2 and RDS are in the same AZ.

Comment: You may want to try using newrelic to see if it can identify any issues for you. I ran into an issue with a third party theme trying to load news off a third party server and it would slow down the admin panel significantly.

Comment: OK, that's a good idea. I've narrowed it down to only Super Admins really having trouble actually. It seems other users generally get a good experience.